# Laravel bcrypt to Android

Tags: java, android

A Web server that uses Laravel is passing me a `bcrypt` password and i need to save it to my android database. The problem is how am i going to compare it so an input from Android? Is there any "`bcrypt`" like method in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jBcrypt is a small java library that provides functions to create and verify bcrypt hashes

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt/0.4

```
BCrypt.checkpw(plaintext, hashedPassword);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't match the generated hash from the Web server(Laravel). The Web hash started with $2y$ but jBcrypt returns $2a$

Comment: @dranrebdino This prefix is a version number. Php's original implementation had a bug that Java's didn't. Have you tried simply changing the prefix before verifying the hash?

Comment: I tried changing the prefix and it worked! thank you very much! cheers!